# OpenLDAP on Ubuntu Server 10.04

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-10.04, openldap

I've configured OpenLDAP following the [Ubuntu guide](http://doc.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html) (with some minor edits, such as setting a proper password, my own domain name, and creating a staff group instead of an example one under people) through all steps except Replication.

Everything works just fine, except I can't use ldapscripts....

When I execute:

```
sudo ldapadduser dave staff
```

I get an LDAP error, and the /var/log/ldapscripts.log states:

```
>> 05/29/11 - 13:22 : Command : /usr/sbin/ldapadduser dave staff
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
Error adding user dave to LDAP
```

I'm pretty lost... I checked backend, frontend, /etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.passwd and the password matches...

My ldapscripts.conf file properly states:

```
SERVER=localhost
BINDDN="cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com"

# The following file contains the raw password of the binddn
# Create it with something like : echo -n 'secret' > $BINDPWDFILE
# WARNING !!!! Be careful not to make this file world-readable
# DEBIAN: /etc/pam_ldap.secret or /etc/ldap.secret are used.
BINDPWDFILE="/etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.passwd"
```

Any ideas are welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the password in to the file in this way:

```
echo -n "yourpassword" > /etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.passwd
```

Comment: This! Unbelievable. +1, thank you! I had pasted my password into the ldapscripts.passwd file in vi. As soon as I did this and only this, it worked. Why is this?

Comment: Vi inserts and end-of-line terminator after every line, including the last one in the file. Check the size of the files written with vi and echo -n.
You can disable this in vi using `:set noendofline binary` before saving the file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the credentials in your ldapscripts.conf file? You can test with `ldapwhoami -x -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com -y /etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.passwd`.